# How to sum a range of data related to each group created with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

In Python pandas data frame, assume that i grouped my data using pandas `groupby()` method an resulted like this:

[image: Pandas Result]

How can i calculate sum of the values from `Third` column, for each group (here are `A` and `B`) separately, so i can have sum values of each main groups in a cell?

Like I could have `12+32+43` in a new cell for group `A` and `145+231+123` in another cell for group `B`.

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
mydf = data.groupby[['First','Second']].sum()
```

Comment: Please provide your code and a sample dataframe so we do not have to duplicate the work we should _assume_ you have done. Read  [minimal verifyable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Comment: sorry i didn't because it had some Persian letters.

Comment: post your expected output

Answer (score 0):

`data.groupby('First').sum()`

No need to group by `Second` column.